# why isn't destroy link working from nested page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app that lets users sign up for a pro membership. If they want to cancel it, they can click this link, which triggers the destroy action on the promembers_controller.rb

```
<%= link_to "Cancel my account", promember_path(@user), :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure?" }, :method => :delete, :class => 'btn btn-mini' %>
```

I've tried to use this link on two different pages and it only works from one of them, namely the user's profile page

```
  http://localhost:3000/lawyer_profiles/22-user-name
```

However, I don't want the cancel subscription link on that page.

If I put the link on the 'show' page of the nested promembers_controller, like this

```
   http://localhost:3000/lawyer_profiles/22-user-name/promembers/40
```

or if I put it on the edit page like this

```
http://localhost:3000/lawyer_profiles/22-user-name/promembers/37/edit
```

then I get this routing error:

```
No route matches [DELETE] "/promembers"
```

I don't understand why it would make a difference where I put that link as long as I have a route for it, which I do

```
  resources :promembers do

     member { post :update_card }

  end
```

I also have an action named 'destroy' in the `promembers_controller.rb`

It might be important to note that, in addition to the un-nested :promembers resource shown above,  my routes.rb file also has :promembers nested like this.

```
  resources :lawyer_profiles do   
     resources :promembers
  end
```

(I'm not sure if having the same resource nested and un-nested could influence link behavior.)

Can you explain why the link isn't working from the nested pages?

Comment: Based on the error, my best guess is that on the pages where it is failing you have not defined `@user`, which you are passing to promember_path. Make sure `@user` is defined correctly in the controller actions for the pages where it isn't working.

Comment: @AlexPeachey good guess. Thanks If you want to write an answer I'll accept it. or if you vote to delete the question I'll do the same because this might not be a great question to keep around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are building your link with a path helper: `promember_path(@user)` and the `@user` variable is being set in the controller action for the page that is working.

On the pages that are not working, you are likely not setting the `@user` variable and so the path helper is being passed nil.

It is true you have a route for [delete] /promembers/:id but you don't have one for [delete] /promembers which is what is generated when you pass a nil into the helper. This causes the no route error.